# Помогите спарсить id друзей пользователя в вк

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Всем привет и заранее спасибо. Я пытаюсь спарсить друзей у определенного пользователя в https://vk.com. Вот страница рандомного пользователя с которой я пытаюсь спарсить id https://vk.com/friends?id=26711&section=all .В блоке с id="list_content находятся еще несколько блоков содержащих сами ссылки class="friends_list_bl".Парсить пытаюсь на python3 selenium.Код результат выдает но id профилей там нету. В коде отсутствуют пароль, логин для входа в соц.сеть. Спарсить надо именно друзей пользователя. В чем заключается ошибка кода?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

lis=[]
ktr = []
link = "https://vk.com/feed?section=source&source="

url="https://vk.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\kevse\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\chromedriver.exe")

try:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("index_email")
    email_input.send_keys("number")
    pass_input = driver.find_element_by_id("index_pass")
    pass_input.send_keys("pass")
    time.sleep(5)
    pass_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get("https://vk.com/id26711")
    time.sleep(2)
    a = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fl_r")
    for elem in a:
        b = (elem.get_attribute('href'))
        ktr.append(b)

    col = (len(ktr[24]))
    c = (ktr[24][42:col])
    link2 =("https://vk.com/friends?id="+c+"&section=all")
    driver.get(url=link2)
    time.sleep(5)

    frlist = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('friends_list_bl') 

    checkbox_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="list_content"]')
    u = driver.find_element('friends_list_bl')
    print(len(u))
    print(u.text)

   
    


finally:
    print(lis)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Почему бы не использовать api vk? https://github.com/python273/vk_api Пример использования api для получения дней рождений друзей: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/47874be20b9adc97c46e3ab1a0647e1cff306a68/vk_api__examples/friends.get%20birthdays.py#L8

Comment: Хочется понять ошибку кода и научиться использовать selenium. К сожалению vk_api не поможет на других сайтах.

Comment: `В коде отсутствуют пароль, логин для входа в соц.сеть` эта инфа доступна для неавторизованного пользователя?

Comment: В вк неавторизированный пользователь не может посмотреть друзей другого пользователя, поэтому в начале надо зайти в аккаунт вк,